# xcode cannot be opened because of a problem

Tags: iphone, xcode

When i want to opened Xcode then i m getting error message. Like "Xcode cannot be opened because of a problem    Check with the developer to make sure Xcode works with this version of Mac OS X. You may need to re-install the application. Be sure to install any available updates for application and Mac OS X...  Click report to see more detailed information and send a report to Apple".

and when i m searching .dmg file in mac i m not getting any file related to xcode so please help me out of this problem.

Thanks & Regards,
Priyanka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have Lion or Snow Leopard? Which version of Xcode do you have?

If you just installed Lion, try downloading Xcode 4. 
Or else just try to reinstall your Xcode: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/index.php

Comment: xcode 4 and other will not be installed if you don't have proper os for them the installer will quit the installation.

Comment: @Ballu What if you had SL and a matching version of Xcode and then upgraded to Lion? It's perfectly possible to have mismatched versions.

Comment: Yes in that case we could conflict the results.Actually i have faced that problem in past the xcode installer set up it is much intelligent that it always check the system requirements when installation is going on .

Answer (score 0):

try to reinstall XCode use this command to remove XCode completely

**sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all**

Comment: I'm having a frustrating time trying to find the `/Developer/Library/` folder...? I have OS X El Capitan 10.11.5.