# Xcode's iOS Simulator cannot be opened

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Error message:

> Check with the developer to make sure Simulator works with this version of OS X. You may need to reinstall the application. Be sure to install any available updates for the application and OS X.

I have installed Xcode version 7.3.1 and OSX -10.11.5 and there are no available updates.

Comment: what simulator are you trying to open ? 5/5s/6/6s ?

Comment: iphone 6s plus ....but even if I try to open 6,6s I am getting the same error

Comment: Do you have any beta version xcode along with your xcode 7.3.1 ? The only solutions seems to re-install the xcode.

Comment: I tried reinstalling couple of times and uninstalled web sense ....but the issue persists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xcode cannot be opened because of a problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483041/xcode-cannot-be-opened-because-of-a-problem)

Answer (score 49):

I got the same error message on macOS 10.12.6 with Xcode 9.0 when trying to run the Simulator directly without opening Xcode, i.e, clicking on a Simulator icon that was dragged to the dock. [image: simulator dock icon]

The solution was to open Xcode from the launchpad. It then presented a dialog announcing that additional components need to be installed. Once the install finished the Simulator app could be run without errors again.

Comment: In my case additional components were already installed for Xcode 9. Starting simulator from xcode instead of stand alone from dock worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

You may need to open Xcode and follow any applicable prompts.

Sometimes, when there's an Xcode update, some pieces of functionality quit working until you go back in and click through a few windows and such.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same error, and found that the Simulator app I was trying to open directly in my Applications folder was an old version, but the newer version was sitting inside /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/

Comment: how you solve this issue, Pls help me. Me too facing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Open XCode and let it install/update any necessary components.

I tried opening the Simulator directly from the applications folder within finder and got this error. I then opened up XCode and installed necessary components. Once these necessary components installed, I was able to open up the simulator fine.